# Book about dinosaurs/raptors that are green or blue, feathered, and are trying to catch/kill a group of humans

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dinosaurs

I borrowed this book from the young adult section of a library between 2008 and 2013 (I've checked the library catalog to no avail).

The plot was something about how there were a group of humans trying to escape / stay away from the dominant species which were feathered dinosaur-like raptors (feathered velociraptors is what I'm picturing) which could be green or blue (and maybe yellow). I think the humans ended up escaping on a boat to an island somewhere.

From what I can recall, the cover was just a green dinosaur head (entirely green) with its eye in the very center.

Comment: [Did the cover look a bit like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dinosaurs-Childrens-Encyclopedia-DK/dp/0241287324)? This isn't the book, but I have a vague memory of book cover like this i.e. a yellow eye in the centre surrounded by green scaly skin.

Comment: Was time travel involved? Or was there another way for humans and dinosaurs to meet?

Comment: John, yes that looks similar to what I'm picturing.

Comment: Clara, no time travel. Just a world where there are humans and dinosaur-ish creatures.